# Equation code in latex

Tags: equations

I need latex code to write equation same as in this picture, 
Can anyone help me?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. In particular, please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) of what you've tried so far.

Comment: I think you should explain your equation more. I don't know, for example, the `s.t.` is in the equation, or `\le` and `=` are aligned, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hope the below may help you:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{align}
&\mathop{\text{Maximize}}\limits_{w_{\text{RF}}}\quad
h^T_{\text{RF}}w_{\text{RF}}\tag{18}\\
&\qquad\text{s.t.}\nonumber\\
&w^T_{\text{RF}}w_{\text{RF}}\leq 1\qquad (a)\nonumber\\
&g^T_{\text{RF}}w_{\text{RF}}= 1\qquad (b)\nonumber
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another proposal to write your equation using the `matrix` enviroment. You may observe a better alignment than your picture. In this case the numbered equation is automatically numbered to start from the number (1).

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\begingroup
\renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{2}
\endgroup
    \begin{matrix}
    \underset{w_{\mathrm{RF}}}{\mathrm{Maximize}} & h^T_{\mathrm{RF}} w_{\mathrm{RF}}\\
    \mathrm{s.t.} & \\
    w^T_{\mathrm{RF}} w_{\mathrm{RF}}\leq 1  & \quad (a)\\
    g^T_{\mathrm{RF}} w_{\mathrm{RF}}= 1 & \quad (b)
    \end{matrix}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```